# Slice of type struct with different structs inside it

Tags: go

I'm trying to create the following json below, but I'm not getting it:

**json**

```
{
  "richResponse": {
    "items": [
      {
        "simpleResponse": {
          "textToSpeech": "foo1",
          "displayText": "foo2"
        }
      },
      {
        "basicCard": {
          "formattedText": "foo3",
          "imageDisplayOptions": "CROPPED"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that I have a `[]struct` called `Items` (slice of structs) and it has 2 different structs `SimpleResponse` and `BasicCard` and I am not able to mount this json.

The errors appear:

> can not use literal SimpleResponse
>
> can not use BasicCard literal

**main.go**

https://play.golang.org/p/Gbl0UNWhqko

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type SimpleResponse struct {
        TextToSpeech string `json:"textToSpeech"`
        DisplayText  string `json:"displayText"`
    }

    type BasicCard struct {
        FormattedText       string `json:"formattedText"`
        ImageDisplayOptions string `json:"imageDisplayOptions"`
    }

    type Items []struct {
        SimpleResponse SimpleResponse `json:"simpleResponse"`
        BasicCard BasicCard `json:"basicCard"`
    }

    type RichResponse struct{
        Items Items `json:"items"`
    }

    group := RichResponse{  
        Items: Items{
            SimpleResponse{"foo1", "foo2"},
            BasicCard{
                FormattedText: "foo3",
                ImageDisplayOptions: "CROPPED",
            },
        },
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(group)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(b)
}
```

Could you help me mount this json?

Comment: Use pointers for the optional fields and the `omitempty` json tag option: https://play.golang.org/p/2caRIciVF66

Comment: It's not generally necessary to use pointers for optional fields.

Comment: @Adrian wouldn't that then produce `"basicCard": {}` in the first element and `"simpleResponse": {}` in the second, which would be not exactly the same as the desired json in the question? Or does omitempty work on empty non-pointer structs?

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you it worked perfectly with pointers.

Comment: @Adrian your solution does not work, the error continues. You tested?

Comment: I may have assumed too much. Added a working playground example.

Answer (score 2):

`Items` is a slice of structs but you're using it as if it's a single `Item` struct. Being a slice with elements of type `Item` the correct syntax would be:

```
group := RichResponse{  
    Items: Items{ // This is a slice
        Item{ // This is an element in the slice
            SimpleResponse{"foo1", "foo2"},
            BasicCard{
                FormattedText: "foo3",
                ImageDisplayOptions: "CROPPED",
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Note that you need to define `Item` as a named type if you don't want some really messy struct literals. Here's a working example on Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/pzO_w2cIeOJ